# Expected size of startup package for a tenure-track position in Finland

Tags: funding, tenure-track, finland

I have an assistant-professor position in the US, but for personal reasons, I am moving to Europe. I was offered a tenure-track position in Finland. I don't know why but I missed to discuss about the startup package during the interview. I asked about it after receiving the job offer, and the dean asked me how much I need.

In the US, I received near $800K for launching my lab and group, but I read that such startup packages are not common in Europe. I do not want to sound unreasonable.

Can you tell me how is the common practice for starting a tenure-track position in Finnish universities?

Comment: I know nothing about such things in Finland, but in the US at least it would be impossible to answer such a question without specifying the field.

Answer (score 8):

There is **very little any public information** on this available anywhere.

I did some googling and here is a summary of what I was able to put together from some random documents written in Finnish (from Helsinki, Tampere, and Oulu): a reasonably normal startup package for a new tenure track or tenured position in Finnish universities appears to be enough funding to hire **1 doctoral student or postdoc for 1–3 years**.

Comment: Is that information specific to some field(s), or is it actually general?